# mount: can't read superblock

Tags: dual-boot, mount, home-directory

I have only one hard drive `/dev/sda`.

In this hard drive, I've installed two Ubuntu systems: one is Ubuntu 16.04, the other is Ubuntu 17.10.

Both of them have the same architecture of file system:

```
sda      8:0    0 12.7T  0 disk
├─sda1   8:1    0  3.1T  0 part /
├─sda2   8:2    0  3.1T  0 part /home
├─sda3   8:3    0 93.1G  0 part [SWAP]
├─sda4   8:4    0 93.1G  0 part
|-------------------------------------
├─sda5   8:5    0  3.1T  0 part
├─sda6   8:6    0  3.1T  0 part
├─sda7   8:7    0 93.1G  0 part
└─sda8   8:8    0 86.6G  0 part [SWAP]
```

`sda1` is the root of Ubuntu 16.04, `sda2` is the `/home` of Ubuntu 16.04.
`sda5` is the root of Ubuntu 17.10, `sda6` is the `/home` of Ubuntu 17.10.

The others are SWAP and boot area.

Besides, both of `/home`s are not encrypted.

Now I'm on the Ubuntu 16.04 and I execute the command as below:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda5 /mnt
```

It works. I can `cd /mnt` to see all things in `sda5`.

However, when I execute `sudo mount /dev/sda6 /mnt`, I get an error:

```
mount: /dev/sda6: can't read superblock
```

I'm sure that the formats of all partitions are ext4. Why can I mount the `/` of the other system but can't I mount the home directory of the other system?

**RE-EDITION**

Now I'm on Ubuntu 17.10 and execute commands as below:

```
me@mymachine:~$ sudo file -s /dev/sda2
/dev/sda2: Linux rev 1.0 ext4 filesystem data, UUID=4443bb9f-69c0-4a3b-9b1b-1dc90a8a42c7 (extents) (large files) (huge files)

me@mymachine:~$ sudo file -s /dev/sda6
/dev/sda6: Linux rev 1.0 ext4 filesystem data, UUID=e86e1f79-fe8e-4408-b7db-7e9a1b6c88dd (needs journal recovery) (extents) (64bit) (large files) (huge files)

me@mymachine:~$ sudo blkid -c /dev/null /dev/sda2
/dev/sda2: UUID="4443bb9f-69c0-4a3b-9b1b-1dc90a8a42c7" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="deb7ebf9-29c8-4f56-9d81-03c1578b7492"

me@mymachine:~$ sudo blkid -c /dev/null /dev/sda6
/dev/sda6: UUID="e86e1f79-fe8e-4408-b7db-7e9a1b6c88dd" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="3eb07932-7176-447d-9b94-e45f1a835a11"
```

To my surprise, I can `mount /dev/sda2 /mnt` when I'm on Ubuntu 17.10...

Comment: Is `/dev/sda6` encrypted?

Comment: @Olorin   No, it isn't.

Comment: Can we see `sudo blkid -c /dev/null /dev/sda6` and/or `sudo file -s /dev/sda6` please

Comment: @steeldriver  done, check my edition.

Comment: @steeldriver  I can `mount /dev/sda2 /mnt` when I'm on Ubuntu 17.10...hmm.... No idea...

Comment: Probably related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/60274/70524